# Possibility of initiating playback of flash video on headless server through the terminal

Tags: flash, unix, html5-video, video-capture

Hey so I have a website  which has video's gathered from places around the web, primarily youtube but a few other's as well. Now I am wondering if there is some way to check link's to make sure they are still available through a unix shell. (My idea is to run a cron to check videos are still available and if not delete them.) I am aware i could use user to do this but it always bothered me and was wondering if there is somehow to check the playback of a flash video though the terminal . Any insight into this would be awesome as I haven't found much on the web. Also note ideally the tech. will work on all video type's including html5.

**update** So it's occured to me that through the you tube api, I could check the status of the video's coming from youtube (which is a start). But I would love to know if there's something else that is not player specific but rather just calls the video to play similar to how a user would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a (possibly modified) version of [get_flash_videos](https://code.google.com/p/get-flash-videos/) to check if a file will download or not, if you don't have an API. The -i parameter appears very helpful in this regard. This utility supports quite a few websites.

Comment: this seem's to be the best answer i will get so I've awarded you the bounty. Thanks again for the help